# Program does not print the return value of a function

Tags: python, function, printing

I have a piece of code to calculate one matrix from another. But when I try to print the output of the function the code runs without any errors but does not print anything. Furthermore, if I try to print the input matrix to the function and then call the function, the original input does not get printed. It prints fine when I don't call this function inf_mat. Does anybody know what might be the reason?

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations

def inf_mat(adjacency, l_max):
    ## Influence matrix - Returns the influence matrix corresponding to the input adjacency matrix
    inf_arr = np.zeros(np.shape(adjacency))
    print(inf_arr)
    norm_mat = adjacency
    for i in range(np.shape(norm_mat)[0]):
        for j in range(np.shape(norm_mat)[1]):
            if norm_mat[i,j] != 0:
                norm_mat[i,j] = 1

    for i in range(np.shape(inf_arr)[0]):
        for j in range(np.shape(inf_arr)[1]):
            ind_lists = []
            for k in range(l_max-1):
                all_ind = [m for m in range(np.shape(adjacency)[1])]
                all_ind.remove(i)
                if j != i:
                    all_ind.remove(j)
                ind_lists.append(list(permutations(all_ind, k+1)))
                  
            pairwise_list = []
            for p in range(len(ind_lists)):
                pairs = []
                for q in range(len(ind_lists[p])):
                    mult_list = [i]
                    for r in range(len(ind_lists[p][q])):
                        mult_list.append(ind_lists[p][q][r])
                    mult_list.append(j)
                    pairs.append(mult_list)
                pairwise_list.append(pairs)

            inf_sum = adjacency[i,j]
            norm_sum = norm_mat[i,j]
            for t in range(len(pairwise_list)):
                for t_ind in range(len(pairwise_list[t])):
                    inf_ele = 1
                    norm_ele = 1
                    for s in range(len(pairwise_list[t_ind])-1):
                        inf_ele *= adjacency[s,s+1]
                        norm_ele *= norm_mat[s,s+1]
                    inf_sum += inf_ele
                    norm_sum += norm_ele

            inf_arr[i,j] = inf_sum/norm_sum

    return inf_arr/l_max

def readFile(Filename):
    fileObj = open(Filename, "r")
    words = fileObj.read().splitlines()
    fileObj.close()
    return words

topo_list = readFile("EMT_RACIPE.topo")
topo_list.remove(topo_list[0])
gene_list = []

for i in range(len(topo_list)):
    topo_list[i] = topo_list[i].split()
    for j in range(2):
        if gene_list.count(topo_list[i][j]) == 0:
            gene_list.append(topo_list[i][j])

adjacency = np.zeros(shape = (len(gene_list),len(gene_list)))

for i in range(len(gene_list)):
    indices = []
    for j in range(len(topo_list)):
        if topo_list[j].count(gene_list[i]) > 0:
            indices.append(j)

    for k in range(len(indices)):
        if topo_list[indices[k]][0] == gene_list[i]:
            if topo_list[indices[k]][2] == '1':
                adjacency[i, gene_list.index(topo_list[indices[k]][1])] = 1
            if topo_list[indices[k]][2] == '2':
                adjacency[i, gene_list.index(topo_list[indices[k]][1])] = -1
        if topo_list[indices[k]][1] == gene_list[i]:
            if topo_list[indices[k]][2] == '1':
                adjacency[gene_list.index(topo_list[indices[k]][0]), i] = 1
            if topo_list[indices[k]][2] == '2':
                adjacency[gene_list.index(topo_list[indices[k]][0]), i] = -1

N22E82 = adjacency
print(N22E82)
inf_N22E82 = inf_mat(N22E82, 10)
print(inf_N22E82)
```

Comment: Can you share sample **EMT_RACIPE.topo** file content? Or can you send a link?

Comment: How big is `adjacency`?

Comment: What happens if you put `print("starting inf_mat")` at the beginning of `inf_mat()`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.